# Unable to access Cloud Firestore files for specific user

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use Cloud Forestore to save user data. The rules I have set up looks like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userID} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userID;

      match /{lists} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
      }
    }
    match /users/test {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

What I try to accomplish is that the user should be able to read everyting in {userID}, including subcollections and subdocuments. In addition the user should be able to write to the {lists} collection and every subcollection and subdocument.

I access the Cloud Firestore like this:

```
db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("lists").document(String.valueOf(document.getDocId()))
                    .set(cloudListInfo)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            error = 0;
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            error = -3;
                            globalVars.logException(TAG, "docInfo:ExportToCloud FAILURE", e);
                        }
                    });
        }
```

The error I get is this:

```
FAILURE:Exception.string:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I can access the "test"-collection and its values.

I have created a record for my user using rules that allowed writing/reading to everything, ala the rules in the "test"-match. This was done prior to my effort to secure the data with more elaborate rules.

I can not understand why this is not working. Most likely it is something trivial, but I've almost gone blind trying to find the reason...

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like it's your **Security Rules** that has the problem.

Try this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userID} {
            allow read: if request.auth != null;

            match /{lists} {
                allow write: if request.auth != null;
            }
        }

        match /users/test {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget that you have to be **logged in** for errors to not occur.

Comment: But with your rules, any user that is logged in can access any users data. The rules I've applied are copied from the docs to ensure user-specific access. Or am I wrong? And I'm logged in.